# Удаление/замена строки в txt файле на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функция, которая должна удалять строку, но она этого не делает! Можете помочь?

```
def delluser(message):
    with open("vip_id.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("vip_id.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != то что нужно удалить:
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: может строка оканчивается на `"\r\n"` и в итоге сравниваемая строка получается отлична от той, что в файле

Answer (score 0):

```
def delluser(message):
    with open("vip_id.txt", "r") as f:
        old_data = f.read()
    new_data = old_data.replace(то что нужно удалить, ' \n')
    with open("vip_id.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(new_data)
```